# What are the relation and differences between reification and type passing semantics?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, polymorphisms

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure says

> **type erasure** refers to the load-time process by which explicit type annotations are removed from a program, before it is executed at run-time. Operational semantics that do not require programs to be accompanied by types are called **type-erasure semantics**, to be contrasted with **type-passing semantics**. The possibility of giving type-erasure semantics is a kind of abstraction principle, ensuring that the run-time execution of a program does not depend on type information. In the context of generic programming, the opposite of type erasure is called **reification**.

- Are both reification and type passing semantics  opposite to type erasure?
- What are the relation and differences between reification and type passing semantics? Do they mean the same?

The best that I can find about them are from the two following books. But I am still not quite sure about my question.

About type erasure vs type passing, *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce says:

> **23.7 Erasure and Evaluation Order**
>
> The operational semantics given to System F in Figure 23-1 is a **type-passing
>   semantics**: when a polymorphic function meets a type argument, the type is
>   actually substituted into the body of the function. The ML implementation of
>   System F in Chapter 25 does exactly this.
>   In a more realistic interpreter or compiler for a programming language
>   based on System F, this manipulation of types at run time could impose a
>   signiﬁcant cost. Moreover, it is easy to see that type annotations play no signiﬁcant role at run time, in the sense that no run-time decisions are made on
>   the basis of types: we can take a well-typed program, rewrite its type annotations in an arbitrary way, and obtain a program that behaves just the same.
>
> For these reasons, many polymorphic languages instead adopt a **type-erasure
>   semantics**, where, after the typechecking phase, all the types are erased and
>   the resulting untyped terms are interpreted or compiled to machine code.

About type erasure vs reification, *Programming Language Pragmatics* by Scott says:

> C# 2.0 was able to employ an implementation based on **reiﬁcation** rather than
>   **erasure**. **Reiﬁcation** creates a different concrete type every time a generic is instantiated with different arguments. Reiﬁed types are visible to the reﬂection library (`csNames.GetType().ToString()` returns "Arbiter 1[System.Double]"),
>   and it is perfectly acceptable to call `new T()` if `T` is a type parameter with a zero-argument constructor (a constraint to this effect is required). Moreover where
>   the Java compiler must generate implicit type casts to satisfy the requirements of
>   the virtual machine (which knows nothing of generics) and to ensure type-safe
>   interaction with legacy code (which might pass a parameter or return a result of
>   an inappropriate type), the C# compiler can be sure that such checks will never
>   be needed, and can therefore leave them out. The result is faster code.

Thanks.